# Dataframe is no longer the same after being saved to Excel and read back in

Tags: r

I create a one-column dataframe with NA filled in the entire column except the last element which is 2 (numeric).  Then I save this dataframe into Excel and read in again. They are no longer the same (both identical and all.equal).

Typeof (the column) is "double" before saving to excel and it is "logical" after reading in. It becomes "double" again when reducing # of "NAs" to 500. I apply "as.numeric" to this column. It does not make two dataframes equal.

```
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(NA,1000), 2))

typeof(df$x)             # "double"
write_xlsx(df, "dfx")
dfx <- read_xlsx("dfx")
typeof(dfx$x)            # "logical"

all.equal(df, dfx)       # "Attributes: < Component “class”: message .....
```

all.equal should be TRUE.

Comment: Excel files don't store data types. You can't "remember" that a column is supposed to be double when you read it back in if all the values are missing. If all the values are missing, will just assume the column is as simple as possible (logical). If you need to store an object and read it back in exactly the same in R, look at the `save()` and `load()` functions, or `saveRDS()`. This isn't going to work with Excel files.

Comment: @MrFlick: But why does `as.numeric()` don't fix the problem and columns are stil unequal?

Comment: `read_xlsx` uses the `guess_max = ` option to limit the number of rows necessary to examine before guessing the column type.  In your case above you have 1000 NA and then a single number, which exceeded the default value of 1000 rows.  If your spreadsheets are very large and irregular you can adjust the limit accordingly.

Comment: @Dave2e. Thanks. I tested guess_max = 2000, too. (Sorry for not mentioning at the beginning). This leads to typeof(dfx$x) to be "double", consistent with the type prior saving. (@MrFlick, there is a way to get around). However, setting guess_max = 2000 does not make all.equal to be true. This is what I want. By the way, I am testing third party codes. I do not have freedom to change read/write packages.

Comment: In case you are interested in, here are extensive discussions in https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/414. No solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for my problem. Just change the read_xlsx statement as follow

```
dfx <- as.data.frame(read_xlsx("dfx", guess_max = nrow(df) ))
```